# passing info to chrome extension from website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i'm trying sending data from website javascript to my chrome extension.
I read about [sending msgs from website](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) and i couldn't make it work.

in my website:

```
$("#button-id").click(function(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("msg", {arg: "1"},
    function(response){alert("got response: " + response);});
});
```

and in background.js (in the chrome extension)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function() {
        alert("in background");
        return "1";
    });
```

I also added to the manifest:

```
   "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": ["*://localhost/project/public/*","http://localhost/project/public/*","*://*/*/*"]
    },
```

and all I'm getting when I'm clicking that button is alert that says "got response undefined".

something that i tried that maybe will help to figure it out:
when I'm on my website, opening chrome developer console, typing "chrome.runtime.sendMessage("jjj");"
I'm getting 'undefined'.

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send a response, you need to pass it to `sendResponse` parameter of the listener, which is the third parameter:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert("in background");
    sendResponse("1");
  }
);
```

One thing to note: if `sendResponse` is going to be called asynchronously, you have to `return true;`

---

Also, when sending a message from a webpage, you have to supply the extension's id as the first parameter. In your example code it's `"msg"`: it must be an extension id.